# How to get complete memberlist for a community

Tags: ibm-sbt

How do I get the complete memberlist for a Community (more than the first 10) using the Java API in the SBTSDK?  It appears that there should be a way to use the GetCommunityMembers and get the total number and page through them.  (sorry if this is too basic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the the CommunityEntity object then call getMembers, and then process the object.

```
String communityUuid = "1dba2e59-05da-4b9a-84e4-2444a6cac251";
Community myComm = new Community(communityUuid); 
MemberList listOfMembers = myComm.getMembers();
```

Then call listOfMembers.iterator(); and process in a for loop (the data element is Member)

The docs are also in the sbtsdk download in docs/javadocs/index.html

Comment: Thanks Paul.  The iterator is definitely what I want to use.  I have been trying to use the high-level APIs for communities from the SBT.  One of them is GetCommunitybyID which provides a list of members - but only 10.  So this is what I have:

String communityUuid = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa4";
CommunityService svc = new CommunityService();
Community community = svc.getCommunity(communityUuid);
if (community.getCommunityUuid() != null) {
Member[] members = app.getCommunityMembers(community);

Do I need to use the low-level APIs instead?

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting above, trying again.    @Paul, do I need to use low-level API instead of the wrapper APIs provided?  
  
    String communityUuid = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa4"; 
    CommunityService   svc = new CommunityService(); 
    Community community = svc.getCommunity(communityUuid); 
    if (community.getCommunityUuid() != null) { 
        Member[] members = app.getCommunityMembers(community);

Comment: no, you shouldn't have to use low-level APIs.  ... did the code above not work? myComm.getMembers() is the preferred way.

Comment: When I use your code I get 'method getMembers() undefined for the type Community'.  

So it looks like my code is using a CommunityService.GetCommunity(UUID) and it looks like your simpler code is using a Community.Community(UUID) to first get the community before getting members.  In the javadoc I don't see a method for getMembers in Community constructor.

Comment: what build # do you have>?

Comment: version: 1.0.0.20130709-1718

Comment: Downloaded/unzipped 20131024-1349.  Any suggestions on how to easily import what I need into Eclipse?

Comment: well, you shouldn't have to change your project. that build should have your getMembers function.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  Got it all to work.  One interesting aspect of this is that I can get a list that includes 'inactive' folks and could then remove them from the membership of the community.  Thanks for your help